# Must $ax + by = d$ and $ax + cy = e$ system of equations contain one solution given the constrains?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let, $a,b,c,d,e$ be constants in the following system of equations.

$ax + by = d, \\ ax + cy = e$

Suppose $b \ne c$ and $a \ne 0$. Must the system of equations have exactly one solution $(x,y)$

I'd like someone to correct me or provide a framework for understanding this.

My answer is No. The reason being is despite $b$ and $c$ not being equal which implies that the two equations are not multiples of each other, the $e$ can account for the discrepency between the two equations and therefore it's potentially equal and have infinitely many solutions? Is this correct? and if so, how do i put this in mathematical terms?

Comment: Hint: Let $A$ be the coefficient matrix for the system. What can you derive from the fact that $\det A = ac-ab \neq 0$ for $b\neq c$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not advanced that far yet. Not sure what you mean by "det".

Comment: determinant $\neq0$ implies the matrix is invertible, i.e., there is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking so deeply about it, you can simply subtract the second equation
from the first so you get, 
$$y(b-c) = (d-e)$$ so $$y=\frac{d-e}{b-c}$$
Now put this in the first equation and you get $$ax + b\cdot ( \frac{d-e}{b-c})=d$$ 
Rearrange and you will get a unique solution $(x,y)$.

The method suggested in the comments is far simpler but since you have not studied determinants this is probably the way to go.

Comment: shouldn't it go from $y(b-c) = (d-e) \therefore y = \left(\frac{d-e}{b-c}\right)$?

Comment: My bad! But you get the gist XD